# dicom viewer add tools

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing one web application for my client. We have one issue. I want to display dicom image on client side. 
Right now we have used https://github.com/ivmartel/dwv. 
I hv tried

html file before Adding css and toolbar

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/dwv-0.22.0.min.js"></script>
            <style type="text/css" >
                body { background: #252525; color: #fff; }
                button {
                    margin: 5px; padding: 10px 10px;
                    border: 0 none; border-radius: 4px;
                    font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;
                    color: #fff; background-color: #444; }
                button:hover { background-color: #555; }
                button:disabled { background-color: #08b; }
                .toolbar { font: 14px arial, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: center; }
                .wl-button, .reset-button { margin-right: 5px; }
                .layerContainer { margin: auto; text-align: center; }
                .imageLayer { left: 0px; }      




            </style>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function() {
                    var imgUrl = document.getElementById("imageHidden").src;
                    dwv.gui.getElement = dwv.gui.base.getElement;
                    dwv.gui.displayProgress = function(percent) {
                    };

                    // create the dwv app
                    var app = new dwv.App();
                    // initialise with the id of the container div
                    app.init({
                        "containerDivId": "dwv",
                        "tools": ["WindowLevel"], // or try "ZoomAndPan"
                    });
                    // load dicom data
                    app.loadURLs([imgUrl]);
                    var range = document.getElementById("sliceRange");
                    range.min = 0;
                    app.addEventListener("load-end", function() {
                        range.max = app.getImage().getGeometry().getSize().getNumberOfSlices() - 1;
                    });
                    app.addEventListener("slice-change", function() {
                        range.value = app.getViewController().getCurrentPosition().k;
                    });
                    range.oninput = function() {
                        var pos = app.getViewController().getCurrentPosition();
                        pos.k = this.value;
                        app.getViewController().setCurrentPosition(pos);
                    }

                };
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    // base function to get elements

                });
            </script>

        </head>
        <body>
 <img id="imageHidden" src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" hidden="true">
            <div id="dwv">

                <!-- Layer Container -->
                <div class="layerContainer">
                    <canvas class="imageLayer">Only for HTML5 compatible browsers...</canvas>
                </div><!-- /layerContainer -->


            </div><!-- /dwv -->
            <input type="range" id="sliceRange" value="0">
        </body>
    </html>
```

This above code displays image only. When i add css and toolbar js files,it shows nothing 
html file after adding toolbar files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>DICOM Web Viewer</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="DICOM Web Viewer (DWV) static version">
        <meta name="keywords" content="DICOM,HTML5,JavaScript,medical,imaging,DWV">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/css/style.css">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/viewers/static/appgui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/viewers/static/applauncher.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css" >
            body { background-color: #222; color: white; font-size: 80%; }
            #pageHeader h1 { display: inline-block; margin: 0; color: #fff; }
            #pageHeader a { color: #ddf; }
            #pageHeader .toolbar { display: inline-block; float: right; }
            .toolList ul { padding: 0; }
            .toolList li { list-style-type: none; }
            #pageMain { position: absolute; height: 92%; width: 99%; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; background-color: #333; }
            .infotl { text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000; }
            .infotc { text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000; }
            .infotr { text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000; }
            .infocl { text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000; }
            .infocr { text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000; }
            .infobl { text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000; }
            .infobc { text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000; }
            .infobr { text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000; }
            .dropBox { margin: 20px; }
            .ui-icon { zoom: 125%; }
            .tagsTable tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #333; }
            .drawList tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #333; }
            button, input, li, table { margin-top: 0.2em; }
            li button, li input { margin: 0; }
            .history_list { width: 100%; }
        </style>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/ext/jquery-ui/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.css">
        <style type="text/css" >
            .ui-widget-content { background-color: #222; background-image: url();}
        </style>
        <!-- Third party (dwv) -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/ext/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/ext/i18next/i18next.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/ext/i18next/i18nextXHRBackend.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/ext/i18next/i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/ext/konva/konva.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/ext/magic-wand/magic-wand.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/ext/jszip/jszip.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Third party (viewer) -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/ext/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/ext/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/ext/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
        <!-- decoders -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/decoders/pdfjs/jpx.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/decoders/pdfjs/util.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/decoders/pdfjs/arithmetic_decoder.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/decoders/pdfjs/jpg.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dicom/decoders/rii-mango/lossless-min.js"></script>
        <!-- Local -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/dwv-0.22.0.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Launch the app -->

    </head>

    <body>

 <img id="imageHidden" src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" hidden="true">
        <!-- DWV -->
        <div id="dwv">

            <div id="pageHeader">

                <!-- Title -->
                <h1>DWV <span class="dwv-version"></span></h1>

                <!-- Toolbar -->
                <div class="toolbar"></div>

            </div><!-- /pageHeader -->

            <div id="pageMain">

                <!-- Open file -->
                <div class="openData" title="File">
                    <div class="loaderlist"></div>
                    <div id="progressbar"></div>
                </div>

                <!-- Toolbox -->
                <div class="toolList" title="Toolbox"></div>

                <!-- History -->
                <div class="history" title="History"></div>

                <!-- Tags -->
                <div class="tags" title="Tags"></div>

                <!-- DrawList -->
                <div class="drawList" title="Draw list"></div>

                <!-- Help -->
                <div class="help" title="Help"></div>

                <!-- Layer Container -->
                <div class="layerDialog" title="Image" id="dwv">
                    <div class="dropBox"></div>
                    <div class="layerContainer">
                        <canvas class="imageLayer">Only for HTML5 compatible browsers...</canvas>
                        <div class="drawDiv"></div>
                        <div class="infoLayer">
                            <div class="infotl"></div>
                            <div class="infotc"></div>
                            <div class="infotr"></div>
                            <div class="infocl"></div>
                            <div class="infocr"></div>
                            <div class="infobl"></div>
                            <div class="infobc"></div>
                            <div class="infobr" style="bottom: 64px;"></div>
                            <div class="plot"></div>
                        </div><!-- /infoLayer -->
                    </div><!-- /layerContainer -->
                </div><!-- /layerDialog -->

            </div><!-- /pageMain -->

        </div><!-- /dwv -->

    </body>
</html>
```

whats wrong in code? any Suggesstions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing all the 'AppLauncher' code needed to launch dwv and load the image. The launcher code is the code you have put in the `window.onload` function of your first html.

Comment: how can i add comment box tool for radioligist in dwv @ivmartel